# How to dynamically change icon on react-google-maps?

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I would like that when clicked on a table, the icon on the map would be updated to another color. But the same does not happen. I don't know how to "refresh" the icon

```
import { GoogleMap, InfoWindow, useJsApiLoader, MarkerF } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import { options } from "../../../../../helpers/lib/MapOptions";
import { IDevice } from "pages/authenticated/DevicesAndAccessories/types";
import { useMapCenter } from "../../hooks/Index";
import { IDeviceReducer, IDeviceSelectedReducer } from "types/types";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { removeSelectedDevice, selectedDevice } from "redux/devices/actions";

const deaIcon: string =
require("../../../../../assets/icons/home-icons/Dea/dea.svg").default;
const deaSelected: string =
require("../../../../../assets/icons/home-icons/Dea/dea-selected.svg").default;

export const GoogleMapsPageMap = () =\> {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const devicesData = useSelector((state: IDeviceReducer) =\> state.allDevices.devices);
const selectedDeviceData = useSelector((state: IDeviceSelectedReducer) =\> state.device);
const center = useMapCenter();

let { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
id: "google-map-script",
googleMapsApiKey: "api_key",
});

return (
<\>
{isLoaded ? (
<GoogleMap
mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
center={center}
zoom={15}
options={options}
>

          <MarkerF position={center}></MarkerF>
    
          {devicesData.map((item: IDevice, index: any) => (
            <MarkerF
              icon={deaIcon} // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
              key={item.id}
              position={devicesData[index].position}
              onClick={() => {
                dispatch(selectedDevice(item));
              }}
            >
              {selectedDeviceData.id === item.id &&
                <InfoWindow
                  position={devicesData[index].position}
                  onCloseClick={() => dispatch(removeSelectedDevice())}
                >
                  <div>{item.name}</div>
                </InfoWindow>
    
    
              }
            </MarkerF>
          ))}
    
        </GoogleMap>
      ) : null}
    </>

);
};
```

I tried using ternary, template string, but I don't know how to change the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// ~ Dependencies
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, MarkerF, OverlayView } from "@react-google-maps/api";
// ~ State Management
// ~ Services
import { options } from "../../../../../helpers/lib/MapOptions";
// ~ Hooks
import { IDeviceReducer, IDeviceSelectedReducer, IUserReducer } from "types/types";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { removeSelectedDevice, selectedDevice } from "redux/devices/actions";
import { InfoBoxStyled } from "./Index.styles";
import { IDevice } from "types/globals";

const deaIcon: string = require("../../../../../assets/icons/home-icons/Dea/dea-icon-map-not-selected.svg").default;
const deaSelected: string = require("../../../../../assets/icons/home-icons/Dea/dea-selected.svg").default;

export const GoogleMapsPageMap = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const devicesData = useSelector((state: IDeviceReducer) => state.allDevices.devices);
  const selectedDeviceData = useSelector((state: IDeviceSelectedReducer) => state.device);
  const userInfo: IUserReducer = useSelector((state: IUserReducer) => state);

  //   const center = {
  //     lat: userInfo.user.position.latitude,
  //     lng: userInfo.user.position.longitude
  // }

  const center = {
    lat: -30.058598,
    lng: -51.16944,
  };

  let { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: "google-map-script",
    googleMapsApiKey: "yoour_api_key",
  });
  const UserMarker: React.FC = () => {
    return <MarkerF position={center}></MarkerF>;
  };
  const DevicesMarkers: React.FC = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {devicesData.map((item: IDevice, index: number) => (
          <MarkerF
            icon={selectedDeviceData.id === item.id ? deaSelected : deaIcon}
            key={item.id}
            position={devicesData[index].position}
            onClick={() => {
              dispatch(selectedDevice(item));
            }}
          >
            {selectedDeviceData.id === item.id && (
              <OverlayView position={devicesData[index].position} mapPaneName={OverlayView.OVERLAY_MOUSE_TARGET}>
                <InfoBoxStyled>{item.name}</InfoBoxStyled>
              </OverlayView>
            )}
          </MarkerF>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoaded ? (
        <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} center={selectedDeviceData.position.lat === 0 ? center : selectedDeviceData.position} zoom={10} options={options}>
          <UserMarker />
          <DevicesMarkers />
        </GoogleMap>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code, the issue with the icon not changing color when the table is clicked is due to the fact that you are not updating the icon prop in the Marker component after the click event.

To solve this issue, you can use a state variable to keep track of the selected device, and update the icon prop based on whether the device is selected or not.

```
import { GoogleMap, InfoWindow, useJsApiLoader, MarkerF } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import { options } from "../../../../../helpers/lib/MapOptions";
import { IDevice } from "pages/authenticated/DevicesAndAccessories/types";
import { useMapCenter } from "../../hooks/Index";
import { IDeviceReducer, IDeviceSelectedReducer } from "types/types";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { removeSelectedDevice, selectedDevice } from "redux/devices/actions";

const deaIcon: string =
require("../../../../../assets/icons/home-icons/Dea/dea.svg").default;
const deaSelected: string =
require("../../../../../assets/icons/home-icons/Dea/dea-selected.svg").default;

export const GoogleMapsPageMap = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const devicesData = useSelector((state: IDeviceReducer) => state.allDevices.devices);
  const selectedDeviceData = useSelector((state: IDeviceSelectedReducer) => state.device);
  const center = useMapCenter();
  const [selectedDeviceId, setSelectedDeviceId] = useState("");

  let { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: "google-map-script",
    googleMapsApiKey: "api_key",
  });

  return (
    <>
      {isLoaded ? (
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
          center={center}
          zoom={15}
          options={options}
        >
          <MarkerF position={center}></MarkerF>
          {devicesData.map((item: IDevice, index: any) => (
            <MarkerF
              icon={
                selectedDeviceData.id === item.id
                  ? deaSelected // Update icon based on selectedDeviceId state
                  : deaIcon
              }
              key={item.id}
              position={devicesData[index].position}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedDeviceId(item.id); // Set selectedDeviceId state on click
                dispatch(selectedDevice(item));
              }}
            >
              {selectedDeviceData.id === item.id && (
                <InfoWindow
                  position={devicesData[index].position}
                  onCloseClick={() => {
                    setSelectedDeviceId(""); // Reset selectedDeviceId state on close click
                    dispatch(removeSelectedDevice());
                  }}
                >
                  <div>{item.name}</div>
                </InfoWindow>
              )}
            </MarkerF>
          ))}
        </GoogleMap>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```